# grails mail verification

Tags: java, email, plugins, grails

I use grails with mail plugin.

An email validity code should be sent to user email. When use clicks the URL/code, 
only after it the account should be created.

Now I can send text email, but I do not know what URL I have to send and how to organize click
on it.

If anyone know how to organize this, please help..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this plugin:

http://www.grails.org/plugin/email-confirmation

Answer (score 0):

As well as the 'email-confirmation' plugin, you can also look at using the 'spring-security-ui plugin'. This plugin depends on the 'spring-security-core' plugin though, which handles all user authentication/authorization and might be overkill if you're just looking for an email registration solution.

The plugin is here: http://grails.org/plugin/spring-security-ui

Documetation on register is here: http://burtbeckwith.github.com/grails-spring-security-ui/docs/manual/index.html